# Removeing from SQLite database takes a long time, causing hangs

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I use a SQLite Database in my app. For a specific action, I want to remove multiple (could be quite some, up to approx. a hundred) entries in a specific table. I have tried doing this by calling `deleteStuffLink()` as many times as needed in a `for` loop, and adding the loop inside the `deleteStuffLink()` method. Both of those ways resulted in a 3 second hang for only 15 items.

What is causing this slow behavior, and how can I resolve it?

**Normal delete method**
`for (String s : nameArray) { deleteStuffLink(s); }`

```
public void deleteStuffLink(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LinkTable 
        + " WHERE " + LT_COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + name + "\";");
    db.close();
}
```

**With loop incorporated**

```
public void deleteAllStuffLink(ArrayList<String> nameArray) {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    for (String s : nameArray) {
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LinkTable 
            + " WHERE " + LT_COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + s + "\";");
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Wrap your entire loop of `execSQL()` calls in a transaction, using `beginTransaction()`, `setTransactionSuccessful()`, and `endTransaction()`.

Comment: in the first one, why continually open/close the db? it's like fulfilling your grocery shopping list by driving the store, buying milk, driving home, dropping off the milk, driving back to the store, buying bread, driving home, etc...

Comment: @CommonsWare: I'm gonna try that. Could you explain why that should help? MarcB: because that's the method I use for deleting single rows as well, it was never designed for deleting multiple rows, I just tried a quick implementation on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As CommonsWare comment,

```
public void deleteAllStuffLink(ArrayList<String> nameArray) {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = getWritableDatabase();
   db.beginTransaction();
    for (String s : nameArray) {
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LinkTable 
            + " WHERE " + LT_COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + s + "\";");
    }
   db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   db.endTransaction();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Could either you or @CommonsWare explain why this is so much faster then doing it like I was before?

Comment: Overhead time saved in commit the operation. Use of transaction only one commit operation performed.

Comment: @Timmiej93: Each database transaction involves disk I/O. By default, each SQL statement is in its own transactions. So, with this code, you move from N transactions down to one. It is much cheaper to do one larger transaction than a lot of little ones.